# How to get closure to execute propely

Tags: ios, swift3, closures

So I am having an issue with when my closure function is being called.

```
private var formatedArticles = [article]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let unformatedData = JsonDataFetcher()

    unformatedData.getFromJSON() { articles in
        self.formatedArticles = unformatedData.addArticles(array: articles)
        print(self.formatedArticles[0])
    }
    print(self.formatedArticles[0])
}
```

So basically when this is run the app crashes on the last print statement because the code inside my closure hasn't been executed yet. When that print is removed the print inside the closure executes... how do I get the closure to run when I want? because the problem now is that I want to use my formatted articles array for other things but I keep getting index out of bounds

Comment: You don't. You do the next step, whatever it is, _inside_ the closure.

Comment: I’ve based a blog post around this and similar questions: http://www.programmingios.net/2019/03/08/you-cant-use-a-value-after-it-has-been-set-by-asyncronous-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how asynchronous code works. The next step has to be taken *inside* the closure. So, like this:

```
unformatedData.getFromJSON() { articles in
    self.formatedArticles = unformatedData.addArticles(array: articles)
    print(self.formatedArticles[0])
    // use self.formatedArticles _here_
}
// do _nothing_ here
```